# SQL LAST() Function not working with phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to query last row from databases, so I use this fucntion `LAST(column_name)`. It doesn't work for me I don't know why.
This is an error message that phpmyadmin replys to me

```
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT LAST(power) FROM f01_r02
LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(power) FROM f01_r0 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

I do follow this link
[SQL LAST() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp)

Actually, I know that there are a lot of ways to obtian lastest row data in mysql, but I want to try this function first so, if it impossible to use this fucntion I will go to another solution.

Comment: The LAST() function is only supported in MS Access.

Comment: Use an order by column desc, then LIMIT 1

Comment: @Saty Thank you so much

Comment: @SloanThrasher This is the way that I will use to query. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL` there is no implementation of the `FIRST()` and `LAST()` aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not support `last()` function, thetefore you cannot use it in mysql.